# Filtering Matrix through field value and multiple relations

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, relations, elementcriteriamodel

I've the following situation:

---

### Accommodations (entry)

- title
- description (textfield)
- ...
- linkedTo (matrix block)

  - Sport (category)
  - targetGroup (category)
  - minimumAge (number)
  - maximumAge (number)

---

What I'm trying to do is fetch all entries (accommodations) related to a sport and targetGroup for a person of a certain age. E.g.: Entries for children with the age of 11 years in the targetGroup 'men/boys' and the sport 'football'.

Finding elements using `relatedTo` works for me, except I'm not able to filter the age. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here. I think it's not possible in craft to find textfield values via the relatedTo method, but the question is: How should I do this?

```
private function get ()
{
    $sport      = $this->findSelectedBySlug('football');
    $targetGroup    = $this->findSelectedBySlug('men-boys');
    $age            = 11;

    $wheres = [
        "and",
        [
            'targetElement' => $sport,
            'field' => "linkedTo.sport"
        ],
        [
            'targetElement' => $targetGroup,
            'field' => "linkedTo.targetGroup"
        ],
        [
            'targetElement' => "<= {$age}",
            'field' => "linkedTo.minimumAge"
        ],
        [
            'targetElement' => "> {$age}",
            'field' => "linkedTo.maximumAge"
        ]
    ];

    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'accomodations';
    $criteria->relatedTo = $wheres;

    return $criteria->find();
}
private function findSelectedBySlug ($slug)
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);

    $criteria->slug = $slug;

    return $criteria->first();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this isn't possible with setting `relatedTo` parameters. But you can pass your ElementCriteriaModel (with all other parameters set) to the [`buildElementsQuery`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ElementsService#buildElementsQuery-detail) method, to prepare a [DbCommand](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/db/DbCommand) object. You can now modify the query as you need (→ Craft documentation for [Database Queries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/database)).

Use [`join`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/db/DbCommand#join-detail) to bring in the "matrixblocks" table and also your Matrix field's content table "matrixcontent_*mymatrixfield*". Then add the min. and max age conditions with [`andWhere`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/db/DbCommand#andWhere-detail).

```
private function addAgeCriteria(ElementCriteriaModel $criteria, $age)
{
    $query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);

    $params = array(
        ':age' => $age
    );

    $conditions = array('and',
        'matrixcontent_mymatrixfield.field_linkedTo_minimumAge <= :age',
        'matrixcontent_mymatrixfield.field_linkedTo_maximumAge >= :age'
    ),

    $query->andWhere($conditions, $params);

    $query->join('matrixblocks matrixblocks', 'matrixblocks.ownerId = entries.id');
    $query->join('matrixcontent_mymatrixfield matrixcontent_mymatrixfield', 'matrixcontent_mymatrixfield.elementId = matrixblocks.id');

    $results = $query->queryAll();

    return EntryModel::populateModels($results);
}
```