# Filter locations by country in Smart Map

Tags: relations, plugin-smartmap

I'm using [Smart Map](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/) to find locations ordered by distance. But I can only set 3 parameters: target, range and units. However, when my range goes beyond the country borders I obviously get results in other countries. I want to list all locations within a country by distance, but limited to that country.

Is it possible to do this? I tried related items, but can't seem to get it to work. And I don't see any option in Smart Map either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, there's no in-plugin way to handle this. However, you can probably do it out-of-plugin, once you've retrieved a larger set of results.

So first, you'd [get the largest possible results set:](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/sorting-entries-by-closest-locations/)

```
{% set params = {
    target: targetLocation,
    range:  10000,
    units:  'kilometers'
} %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.myFieldHandle(params).order('distance').find() %}
```

Then, you'd cycle through those results to filter only the entries from your desired country:

```
{% set desiredCountry = 'France' %}
{% set filteredByCountry = [] %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.myFieldHandle.country == desiredCountry %}
        {% set filteredByCountry = filteredByCountry|merge([entry]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Once you've done that, you'll have a `filteredByCountry` array of entries, which should be exactly the results set you were looking for.

Comment: I did it the exact same way before I read your post :) Thanks anyway for the quick response! Love the power of Twig!

Answer (score 5):

What I've done to do something very similar is to add a template variable to my BusinessLogic plugin, that takes the ElementCriteriaModel, prepared with all other parameters e.g. section, limit and SmartMap set. The plugin then translates the model into a [Yii CDbCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand) using [`buildElementsQuery`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ElementsService#buildElementsQuery-detail), adds the additional conditions to the query and returns the further filtered entry models to the template.

Here's my service function with modifications for your country filtering needs. It#s untested but should probably work as is:

```
public function addCountryCriteria(ElementCriteriaModel $criteria, $country)
{
    $query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);

    // Add where condition for country filter
    $params = array(':country' => $country);
    $conditions = array('smartmap_addresses.country = :country');

    $query->andWhere($conditions, $params);

    // Join addresses table to bring in the state
    $query->leftJoin('smartmap_addresses smartmap_addresses', 'smartmap_addresses.elementId = entries.id');

    // Get query results and populate entry models
    $results = $query->queryAll();

    return EntryModel::populateModels($results);
}
```

Also have a look at my other answers on how to add conditions to CDbCommand from the template:

- [How do I select entries that have a particular block type?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/10149/125)
- [Filtering Matrix through field value and multiple relations](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/9999/125)

Comment: Great answer! For folks comfortable with plugin dev, this would be a slick way to pull it off in the initial query. My answer caters more towards folks who'd rather just filter it in Twig. :)

Comment: Yes exactly my thoughts, now there's two good answers! :)

Comment: I can only select one correct answer to this. I haven't tried your way, but it looks very good! Thanks!

Comment: @TomDeSmet try it, it shouldn't take longer than 5mins. to set this up. Do you need pagination – works with this approach. ;)

Comment: Colleague of mine is allready putting the site live and I'm allready working on another project :) Deadlines, deadlines! ;)

Comment: wow that is pretty awsm. i might be able to use this approach in a plugin i'm working on right now. thanks!

Comment: @bhuBouevidya you should also have a look at this follow-up: [Modify ElementCriteria and use it for paginate](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/12189/125)

Comment: @carlcs thx for that tip! that was a great answer to that question. cheers...